# Why and when is the R stop button greyed out?

Tags: r

I have a long calculation running (for days). I can stop it and restart it as desired, as I can save the output and start from where I left off, but I would appreciate the option of doing so without quitting (or force quitting) R, i.e. by just pressing the red stop button in the GUI. However this seems to be impossible in some instances of running the exact same calculation (or sort of calculation): the stop button is greyed out. I would like to know if there's a criterion determining when and why this happens, and a solution to avoid the force quit option.
I'm running R version 3.0.1 (GUI Cocoa 1.61) on a Mac OS 10.7.5, 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide your Operating System, R-version, and which GUI you're using.    All the same, to avoid ungraceful termination of your process, consider a built-in "halt" every N cycles. This could be done with, e.g. the `prompt` function.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Good advice, but I don't think you mean `prompt`. Maybe `scan` or `readline`?

Comment: If the computation is taking place in called C or Fortran code, then the stop button will have no effect. It can only interrupt R interpreter computations.

Comment: @Thomas  Yes, I apologize.  `readline` , i.e. forcing the process to pause until the user provides input, was my intent.

Comment: @James Thanks. However how do you explain that the same code runnning on (formally though not substantially) the same input is sometimes interruptible and sometimes not?